# AT+CSQ? returns error

Tags: arduino-uno, sim900

I need help, i am working with Arduino UNO and a GPRS shield, which is powered with an adapter that outputs 12v 500mA. The sim card is placed properly, i checked this with the **AT+CPIN?** command, but when i try to check the signal level with **AT+CSQ?**, it just return **error**. Please can someone help me.

[image: ERROR IMAGE FORM SERIAL MONITOR]

Comment: Same problem, was working previously - get the feeling it's possibly a configuration that's missing to enable, same thing happens with `AT+CBC` too, immediate `ERROR` reply.

Comment: OK. If you find any solution please let me know @James

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AT+CSQ?` isn't a valid command, however `AT+CSQ` *is* - remove the `?`.

Comment: Ok thanks man. At least I know know the source of the problem.

Comment: @lilfancy no worries, worth checking the documentation it probably varies between modules (I’ve verified with a SIM800L model). Also, slightly alarmed by your power supply.... seems far too much voltage & far too little current for a typical GSM module, which one are you using?

Comment: Am using sim800 model

Answer (score 1):

The command appears to be wrong. Probably these are what you were looking for:

`AT+CSQ=?`: This command is to request the supported RSSIs (Received Signal Strength Indication) and BERs (Bit Error Rate). You might want to get this information before requesting the current cell signal level.

`AT+CSQ`: And this command is to request the current cell signal level.

Here is the result from my SIM808 module:

```
AT+CSQ=?
+CSQ: (0-31,99),(0-7,99)
OK

AT+CSQ
+CSQ: 25,0
OK
```

So that means:

`0-31,99`: Supported RSSIs

`0-7,99`: Supported BERs

`25,0`: Currently, the RSSI value is `25` and the BER value is `0`

Please refer [here](https://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/signal-quality/) for further details.